# Undefined Variable Error While Calling a Function

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, e-commerce, online-store

I'm working on an online store with PHP and in for this project I have made a db with some custom tables such as Brands, Categories, ...

Then in order to retrieve data from db, I made this `connect.php` file which goes like this:

```
<?php 
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","myshop");
?>
```

After that I created a new file called `get_cats.php` which gets data from categories table:

```
    <?php 
require ('connect.php');
function get_cats(){
    $get_cats = "select * from categories";
    $run_cats = mysqli_query($con,$get_cats);
    while($row_cats=mysqli_fetch_array($run_cats)){
        $cat_id = $row_cats['cat_id'];
        $cat_title = $row_cats['cat_title'];
        echo "
            <div class='panel panel-default'>
                <div class='panel-heading'>
                    <h4 class='panel-title'><a href='index.php?cat=$cat_id'><strong>$cat_title</strong></a></h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        ";
    }
}
?>
```

Then at my `index.php` file I simply called the function:

```
<h2 class="BTitrBold">Categories</h2>
<div class="panel-group category-products BHoma" id="accordian">
<?php get_cats(); ?>
</div><!--/category-products-->
```

But whenever I load the page I get this error message:

**Notice: Undefined variable: con in get_cats.php on line 5**

And line 5 of `get_cats.php` is this:

> $run_cats = mysqli_query($con,$get_cats);

However as you can see in the codes, I have correctly included the db connection file in this file. So I don't know why I receive this error!

So if you know, please let me know.. I really appreciate that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `global $con;` to your function.  It is a global variable and is not automatically accessible by your function.